# Phoenix started throwing (UndefinedFunctionError) function :crypto.rand_bytes/1 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

After and update to my system - MAC, my phoenix app compile just fine but throw this error any time I hit any route.

> Server: localhost:4000 (http) Request: GET /
>   ** (exit) an exception was raised:
>       ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :crypto.rand_bytes/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:
>
> ```
>   * rand_seed/0
>   * rand_seed/1
>
>     (crypto) :crypto.rand_bytes(20)
>     (plug) lib/plug/request_id.ex:59: Plug.RequestId.generate_request_id/0
>     (plug) lib/plug/request_id.ex:48: Plug.RequestId.get_request_id/2
>     (plug) lib/plug/request_id.ex:42: Plug.RequestId.call/2
>     (olars) lib/olars/endpoint.ex:1: Olars.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
>     (olars) lib/plug/debugger.ex:93: Olars.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
>     (olars) lib/olars/endpoint.ex:1: Olars.Endpoint.call/2
>     (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
>     (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
> ```

My mix.exs

```
{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.0"},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
      {:phoenix_haml, github: "chrismccord/phoenix_haml"},
      {:mariaex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
      {:arc,  "~> 0.5.2"},
      {:arc_ecto, "~> 0.3.2"},
      {:ex_aws, "~> 0.4.10"},
      {:httpoison, "~> 0.9"},
      {:poison, "~> 2.0"},
      {:ecto, "~> 2.0.2", override: true},
      {:plug_auth, github: "smpallen99/plug_auth"},
      {:comeonin, "~> 2.1.0"},
      {:phoenix_calendar, "~> 0.1.2"},
      {:httpotion, "~> 3.0.0", override: true},
      {:timex, "~> 3.0"},
      {:quantum,github: "c-rack/quantum-elixir"},
      {:calendar, "~> 0.16.1"},
      {:uri_query, "~> 0.1.1"},
      {:scrivener, "~> 2.0"},
      {:scrivener_list, "~> 1.0"},
      {:number, "~> 0.5.0"},
      {:xlsxir, "~> 1.4.1"},
      {:new_relic, "~> 0.1.1"},
      {:retry, "~> 0.7"},
      {:credo, "~> 0.8", only: [:dev, :test], runtime: false}
```

**Elixr version: Elixir 1.4.5**
**Erlang Version: 20**

Let me know if you guys need any other info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @mudasobwa

> put an explicit `{:plug, "~> 1.3"}` in your `mix.ex` file.

Fixed this issue.

Thanks everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 6):

`:crypto.rand_bytes/1` was [removed in OTP 20](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/1ad18832cb21fac5a5b513005f1e6a5ffd7d0329). You should use [:crypto.strong_rand_bytes/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#strong_rand_bytes-1) instead.

In this case, it looks like you need to update plug to have [this commit](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/commit/5f8ae747d23580228c66b53260fff681555b822f). You can run `mix deps.update plug` to do this.

Comment: Already done that without any success... my plug version `plug 1.1.9`, looks like it is locked to this versions, but as show on my mix.ex i do not have it locked at any version.

Comment: @Renews put an explicit `{:plug, "~> 1.3"}` in your `mix.ex` file.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks, this made it work, will use your comment as response to this issue.